# Multiple Joins Tables into one Query becomes Read Only

Tags: sql-server, ms-access-2007, relational-database, left-join

I left joined two tables to the parent table. I want to be able to create a query so I don't have to use subforms when I am creating an interface to enter in the data.

When I crate a query, it is read only. Are queries only editable when there is only one relationship between two tables? CompID from Com, is an autonumber.

```
SELECT dbo_Com.*, dbo_list.*, dbo_Inv.*
FROM (dbo_Complaint LEFT JOIN dbo_Checklist ON dbo_Com.CompID=dbo_list.CompID) LEFT JOIN dbo_Inv ON dbo_Com.CompID=dbo_Inv.CompID;
```

Comment: sql server and ms-access are two different things - which are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick googling found this:  http://www.fmsinc.com/Microsoftaccess/query/non-updateable/index.html  The article looks pretty good.

"Reasons why a Query or Recordset is not Updateable

There are many reasons why your data may not be updateable. ... 
Queries with multi-table joins that aren't on key fields"